# How to convert synchronous function invocation to an observable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Is there a standard way or creater in **RxJS 6** lib which would convert a function invocation into an observable like this ?

```
const liftFun = fun => {
    try {
        return of(fun())
    } catch (err) {
        return throwError(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To observable

```
 const liftFun=fun=>new Observable(obs=>{
        try {
            return obs.next(fun)
        } catch (err) {
            return obs.error(err)
        }
    })
```

Or you want to convert to operator function to be used in `pipe` chain

```
const liftFun = fun => mergeMap(fun=>({
    try {
        return of(fun())
    } catch (err) {
        return throwError(err)
    }
})
```